# C# For Loop being temperamental

Tags: c#, for-loop, graphics

For some reason, the loop only prints 1-3 circles to the panel unless the MessageBox.Show is called. it should print the number of circles the user input into the textbox. I don't understand why that MessageBox being called matters, why the loop decides not to do more than a few circles if the Box is not called. it should do the full number of loops around asked.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (NumberCirclesText.Text != "" && Convert.ToInt32(NumberCirclesText.Text) < 100)
        for (int x = 0; x < Convert.ToInt32(NumberCirclesText.Text); x++)

        {
            int y = x + 1;

            Random myrandom = new Random();
            int xcoord;
            int ycoord;
            ycoord = myrandom.Next(DrawSpace.Width);
            xcoord = myrandom.Next(DrawSpace.Height);
            int r = myrandom.Next(255);

            SolidBrush mybrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(myrandom.Next(255), myrandom.Next(255), myrandom.Next(255)));
            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = DrawSpace.CreateGraphics();
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(ycoord, xcoord, 30, 30);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Transparent, rectangle);
            graphics.FillEllipse(mybrush, rectangle);

            //MessageBox.Show("There are " + y + " circles on the panel.");
            NoOfCircles.Text = y.ToString();

        }


    }
```

Comment: Move the instatiation of `Random` out of the `for` loop. Why? Read the MSDN, please. This site is not a free debugging service; learn to use a debugger.

Comment: ah I feel like a fool it was that simple. yes the answer people are giving makes sense...time for more reading up though i should of spotted that. thanks, just lock this mods...

Answer (score 3):

The message box is a red-herring: it's the fact the message box causes a non-trivial delay that things work. You're creating a new `Random` object each iteration, but each iteration is so fast, the objects will produce the same "random" sequence. With the same "random" inputs, the circles appear (mostly) overlapped.

The simple fix, then, is to just declare and create the `Random` object outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR Version:** just put the line **`Random myrandom = new Random();`** before the loop.

To understand the cause of this you first need to understand how computers generate random numbers:

Since a computer is not a very random machine, it cannot generate true random numbers, it can only generate **pseudo-random** numbers - numbers that **seem** random. The way computers do this is when given a starting value (called `a seed`), they apply some first-grade maths to it, and get a **pseudo-random** number. When asked to generate another number, they simply apply the actions they did to the starting value to the previously generated number.

---

Now that you know how computers generate numbers that look like they are random, you may have one question - Where does the starting value come from?

Well, since when given the same starting value the computer will generate the same sequence of random numbers, we need some value that constantly changes. What changes any second? Time! Computers use the amount of milliseconds since epoch (usually January 1st, 1970) as their seed to generate random numbers.

In .NET (which includes C#), the way to tell the computer to use the time to generate a random sequence, is by creating a new Random object, `Random myrandom = new Random();`

To get the next number in the sequence, you call `myrandom.Next();`.

Since your code loops and creates a new Random object every iteration, and since every iteration is fast enough so the time does not change, each new Random object has the same `seed`, and so when you're asking it for a random number it gives you the first in its sequence. Because the seed of all the Random objects is the same, the first random number each one generates will be identical.

---

Now after you've understood the problem, **the solution**:

In order to get different random numbers each time you can do **one of the following**:

- Either have each new Random object have a **different seed**, which means
  at least a millisecond has to pass before the for loop repeats.
- Or just **use one Random object** (its seed is the time when the for loop
  starts) and every time you want a random number just ask the same
  object for the next number in the sequence.

Since the first approach requires you to slow down your loop, which is stupid unless you don't have another option, choose the second solution, which is to declare the Random object outside the loop.